# How to stop Getting streamcurrupted exception in writing object second time in Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, exception, stream

I'm getting a `streamCorruptedException` in the client when I try to get an object from a server.

At first when the client connects to the server it works well, but when I try to connect a second client or when it runs a second time, the error occurs. I also tried to reset the stream on server end but it hasn't worked.
**EDITED :**

The following is my **SERVER** code:

```
       Socket clientSocket=null;
            BufferedReader rdr=null;
            ObjectOutputStream objwriter=null;
            String name="";
            audioReceiver = new TAudioReceiver(ser);
            videoReceiver = new TVideoReceiver(ser);
            fileReceiver = new TFileReceiver(ser);
            //audioReceiver.start();
            //videoReceiver.start();
            //fileReceiver.start();
            InputStream cliIn=null;
            OutputStream cliOut = null;
            ClientDetails client=null;


            while(true)
            {
                objwriter=null;
                clientSocket = ser.MainSocket().accept();
                cliIn = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                cliOut = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                client = new ClientDetails(clientSocket);
                rdr= new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(cliIn));
                name = rdr.readLine();
                System.out.println("Client connected '"+ name +"'");

                boolean a = ser.clientsMainSockets.AddClient(name, client);
                if(a){
                    ser.clientsNames = ser.clientsMainSockets.ClientNames();

                    wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cliOut));
                    wr.write("OKM");
                    wr.write('\n');
                    wr.flush();
                    objwriter = new ObjectOutputStream(cliOut);
                    //Thread.sleep(1000);
                    objwriter.writeObject(ser.clientsNames);
                    objwriter.flush();
                    clientSocket =null;
                    cliIn = null;
                    cliOut = null;

                    client = ser.clientsMainSockets.Value(name);

                    TMessageHandler msghdl = new TMessageHandler(ser, client.InputStream() , client.OutputStream(), name);
                    clientHandler.add(msghdl);
                    msghdl.start();
                    System.out.println("Starting process for client");
                    objwriter.reset();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                else{

                        wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cliOut));
                        wr.write("ERROR");
                        wr.write('\n');
                        wr.flush();
                }


            }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

and following is **client** code :

```
 mainSock = new Socket(serverIp,serMainPort);
            serOut = mainSock.getOutputStream();
            serIn = mainSock.getInputStream();
            buffWr= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(serOut));
            //serOut = mainSock.getOutputStream();
            //serIn = mainSock.getInputStream();
            buffWr.write(myName);
            buffWr.write('\n');
            buffWr.flush();
            buffRdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serIn));
            String per="";
            per = buffRdr.readLine();
            System.out.println(per);
            if(per.equals("OKM"))
            {

                objin = new ObjectInputStream(serIn);
                ClientsName = (String[])objin.readObject();
                System.out.println("Client no.'"+ ClientsName.length );
                msgHandler = new TMainHandler(this, serOut, serIn);
                msgHandler.start();
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception("User Already exisits. Choose Another name.");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Those sleep() calls are literally a waste of time.

Comment: I suspect they there to simulate breaks between packets or different streams.  Really they are a work around which shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix text and binary streams as this often leads to confusion unless you really know what you are doing.

I suggest you wrap `mainSock.getInputStream()` and `mainSocket.getOutputStream()` once for the life of the stream and *only* use that. i.e. don't call it more than once.

Comment: please have a look , i have changed it but still getting same error.

Comment: You are still wrapping it in more than one place.  You need to decide how you want to wrap it and do that **only once**.

Comment: actually in server , this is thread which will receive a client and start another thread to work woth that client by sending those streams to child thread in it. and than loop will start again and recive those streams to send to child thread , can you please explain more how what should i do , thank you

Comment: I would pass just the socket to the child thread and not do anything with the socket before this happens.  This way there is no streams to pass.  Then you create two streams, one for input and one for output and you use only these.

Comment: BTW I suspect you are using sleep to get your program to work.  This is a bad idea as it is unreliable.  Instead you should write code so that the delays are not needed.

Comment: im also adding those sockets in custom table consisting hash table by calling add client function. As you say the socket data lose in every loop so what do you say tha the socket which is saved in hashtable can be used to get streams and use those streams.?

Comment: In that case, I would have a object of a custom class which holds the Socket and the two Stream wrappers.  This way you can always use the same wrappers each time.

Comment: I am saving the socket and client came in class having hashtable also. will it work ? im saving their , will it work by getting from there or i have to create custom classes?

Comment: You should add an instance of a custom class as the value of your collection.  There are many things you are likely to want to associate with your Socket such as your handler, and session state.

Comment: please have a look on new code i created new clientdata class taking a socket and settings its streams to its private data and im using that class in list to add and sending those streams by getting them. but still same error is occuring.

Comment: You are creating a BufferedReader and an ObjectInputStream which I keep telling you won't work. Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: so you mean i need to use only objectinputstream in order to read string and object ? can you please tell me how to read string via objectinputstream.
and also please have a look on changes on server sided code i have made a list in it of custom classes , is it OK ?

Comment: You can write it with `writeObject("OK")` and read it with `String text = (String) in.readObject();` just like you read the other object. You can also use writeUTF/readUTF but I would try writeObject/readObject for everything to start with.

Comment: also can you tell me which are the good practices in working with streams in java to avoid these types of problems , thanks